# Devise with remote: true without override devise methods

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, devise

I'm using devise with Rails 4.1 and I'm trying unsuccessfully to send devise forms by `AJAX`.

If I simply put `remote: true` at the form my return became a text:

```
Invalid email or password.
```

Is that a way to render a file called `create.js.erb` placed on `views/devise/sessions` without overriding devise methods? If not, what is the best way to do this override?

Comment: try this http://natashatherobot.com/devise-rails-sign-in/

Comment: @NitinVerma will try it. But, isn't there a way to render a `JS` file in the callback instead a `JSON`?